# Differentiation step

Tags: derivatives

How should I go from

$P_{n}(x)*\frac{d}{dx}[P_{m}^{'}(x)(1-x^2)]-P_{m}(x)*\frac{d}{dx}[P_{n}^{'}(x)(1-x^2)]$

to

$\frac{d}{dx}[(1-x^2)(P_{n}'(x)P_{m}(x)-P_{m}'(x)P_{n}(x))]$

Comment: It's easier to prove the other way around.

Comment: Yeah true, but I am trying to get it this way :/

Comment: Why the stubbornness?  If you have expressions $A = B = C$, then it is the same as writing $C = B = A$.

Comment: True, can't say the opposite, but what if you're only given A and you have to find B?

Comment: Depending on the situation, for your question, it is not too difficult to get from the first expression and arrive at the last expression.  You only need to think about Leibnitz's Product Rule.  However, your work would be very much the same, were you to do it in the reverse direction (which would be easier).